# gcc error "expected ')' before '[' token"

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I am receiving these errors while attempting to compile my program with GCC and i'm not sure whats causing them.

```
functions.h:21: error: expected ')' before '[' token
functions.h:22: error: expected ')' before '[' token
functions.h:23: error: expected ')' before '[' token
functions.h:25: error: expected ')' before '[' token
functions.h:26: error: expected ')' before '[' token
functions.h:27: error: expected ')' before '[' token
```

My program compiles fine in visual studio 2012.

Heres the header file that seems to be causing the errors.

```
struct subject
{
    char year[5];
    char session;
    char code[8];
    char credit[3];
    char mark[4];
};

struct data
{
    char name[30];
    char id[30];
    char cc[30]; 
    char course[80];
    struct subject subjects[30];
    int gpa;
};

void displayRecord(data [], int);
int nameSearch(data [], char [], int [], int);
void editRecord(data [], int, int);
char getChar(const char [], int);
int getData(data []);
void displayData(data []);
void deleteRecord(data [], int, int);
```

I'm invoking the compiler like this:

```
gcc -o test functions.cpp functions.h main.cpp
```

I'm stumped so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would it be too much to ask which is line 21?

Comment: This code doesn't exhibit the problem! Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: How are you invoking gcc?

Comment: void displayRecord(data [], int); is line 21

Comment: Invoking gcc with gcc -o test functions.cpp functions.h main.cpp

Comment: It works: http://ideone.com/3Ybwg2

Comment: Why is the question tagged C++?

Comment: data is not a type, struct data is.

Comment: Remove `functions.h` from the command line! It tries to compile `functions.h` using the default language (C). However, headers are not compiled independently, they are compiled by being included into other translation units.

Answer (score 5):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that your visual studio is compiling the code as C++ while gcc is compiling it as C. Since you're missing the `struct` keyword before `data` in your function parameters the C compiler doesn't know what to do. Try running it through g++ instead of gcc (and possibly make sure your including source file's extension is `.C` or `.cpp`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, compiling the provided code with gcc gives the reported error.

Comment: @David Heffernan At least with gcc 4.4 and 4.5 I get the same error as the OP compiling with gcc.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are passing `functions.h` to the compiler. That is an include file and you should just let the two .cpp files include it. There's no need to pass it in your command line invocation of the compiler. Simply remove `functions.h` from your command line invocation of gcc.

Since this is C++, you should be using g++ rather than gcc to compile. Since you used `gcc`, the compiler treated `functions.h` as being C, and the code not valid C.

So, I think your compilation should be

```
g++ -o test functions.cpp main.cpp
```

Comment: The `.cpp` suffix tells `gcc` to treat `functions.cpp` and `main.cpp` as C++ source. But the file `functions.h`, which you pass on the `gcc` command line, causes `gcc` to treat it as C source. You *can* compile a header file directly, but that's useful only to check for errors. And you should use `g++` rather than `gcc` to compile C++, though it really only matters during linking.